# CKEditor 5: How can I load to/save from model instead of view?

Tags: ckeditor

My application uses CKEditor 5 to allow users to edit rich text data. These texts support some application-specific custom elements (Web Components), and I want to extend CKEditor with custom plugins that support inserting such custom elements. I seem to be *almost* there, but I'm having some difficulties getting these custom elements into and out of the CKEditor instance properly.

### Current plugin implementations

I mainly followed the [Implementing an inline widget](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/tutorials/implementing-an-inline-widget.html) tutorial from the CKEditor 5 documentation. As an example, I would like to support a custom element like `<product-info product-id="123"></product-info>`, which in CKEditor should be rendered as a simple `<span>` with a specific class for some styling.

In my editing plugin, I first define the extension to the schema:

```js
const schema = this.editor.model.schema;
schema.register('product-info', {
  allowWhere: '$text',
  isInline: true,
  isObject: true,
  allowAttributes: [ 'product-id' ]
});
```

I then define the upcast and downcast converters, closely sticking to the tutorial code:

```js
const conversion = this.editor.conversion;
conversion.for('upcast').elementToElement({
  view: {
    name: 'span',
    classes: [ 'product-info' ]
  },
  model: (viewElement, { writer: modelWriter }) => {
    const id = viewElement.getChild(0).data.slice(1, -1);
    return modelWriter.createElement('product-info', { 'product-id': id });
  }
});

conversion.for('editingDowncast').elementToElement({
  model: 'product-info',
  view: (modelItem, { writer: viewWriter }) => {
    const widgetElement = createProductInfoView(modelItem, viewWriter);
    return toWidget(widgetElement, viewWriter);
  }
});

conversion.for('dataDowncast').elementToElement({
  model: 'product-info',
  view: (modelItem, { writer: viewWriter }) => createProductInfoView(modelItem, viewWriter)
});

function createProductInfoView(modelItem, viewWriter) {
  const id = modelItem.getAttribute('product-id');
  const productInfoView = viewWriter.createContainerElement(
    'span',
    { class: 'product-info' },
    { isAllowedInsideAttributeElement: true }
  );
  viewWriter.insert(
    viewWriter.createPositionAt(productInfoView, 0),
    viewWriter.createText(id)
  );
  return productInfoView;
}
```

### Expected behavior

The idea behind all this is that I need to support the custom `<product-info>` elements stored in user data in the backend. CKEditor, which is used by users to edit that data, should load these custom elements and transform them into a styled `<span>` for display purposes while editing. These should be treated as inline widgets since they should only be able to be inserted, moved, copied, pasted, deleted as a whole unit. A CKEditor plugin should allow the user to create new such elements to be inserted into the text, which will then also be `<span>`s in the editing view, but `<product-info>`s in the model, which should also be written back to the backend database.

In other words, I expected this to ensure a direct mapping between element `<product-info product-id="123"></product-info>` in the model, and `<span class="product-info">123</span>` in the view, to support inserting and moving of `<product-info>` elements by the user.

### Actual result

In short, I seem to be unable to get CKEditor to load data containing `<product-info>` elements, and unable to retrieve the model representation of these custom elements for backend storage. All operations to insert data to CKEditor from source, or to retrieve CKEditor data for sending to the backend, seem to operate on the view.

For example, if I preload CKEditor contents either by setting the inner content of the element that is replaced with the editor instance, or inserting it like this:

```js
const viewFragment = editor.data.processor.toView(someHtml);
const modelFragment = editor.data.toModel(viewFragment);
editor.model.insertContent(modelFragment);
```

I see the following behavior (verified using CKEditor Inspector):

- When inserting the custom element, i.e. `<product-info product-id="123"></product-info>`,  the element is stripped. It's not present in either the model nor the view.
- When inserting the view representation, i.e. `<span class="product-info">123</span>` I get the representation that I want, i.e. that same markup in CKEditor's view, and the `<product-info product-id="123"></product-info>` tag in the model.

This is exactly the opposite of what I want! In my backend, I don't want to store the view representation that I created for editing purposes, I want to store the actual custom element. Additionally:

- My UI plugin to insert new product info elements, uses a command that does the following:

```js
execute({ value }) {
  this.editor.model.change( writer => {
    const productInfo = writer.createElement('product-info', {
      'product-id': value
    });
    this.editor.model.insertContent(productInfo);
    writer.setSelection(productInfo, 'on');
  });
}
```

which also works as I want it to, i.e. it generates the `product-info` tag for the model and the `span` for the view. But, of course, when loading an entire source text when initialising the editor with data from the backend, I can't use this `createElement` method.

Conversely, in order to retrieve the data from CKEditor for saving, my application uses `this.editor.getData()`. There, these proper pairs of `<product-info>` model elements and `<span>` view elements get read out in their view representation, instead of their model representation – not what I want for storing this data back!

### The question

My question is: what do I need to change to be able to load the data into CKEditor, and get it back out of the CKEditor, using the custom element, rather than the transformed element I want to show only for editing purposes? Put differently: how can I make sure the content I insert into CKEditor is treated as the model representation, and how do I read out the model representation from my application?

I'm confused about this because if the model representation is something that is only supposed to be used internally by CKEditor, and not being able to be set or retrieved from outside – then what is the purpose of defining the schema and these transformations in the first place? It will only ever be visible to CKEditor, or someone loading up the CKEditor Inspector, but of no use to the application actually integrating the editor.

### Sidenote: an alternative approach

For a different approach, I tried to forgo the transformation to `<span>`s entirely, and just use the custom element `<product-info>`, unchanged, in both the model and the view, by using the General HTML Support functionality. This worked fine, since this time no transformation was needed, all I had to do was to set the schema in order for CKEditor to accept and pass through the custom elements.

The reason I can't go with this approach is that in my application, these custom components are handled using Angular Elements, so they will actually be Angular components. The DOM manipulation seems to interfere with CKEditor, the elements are no longer treated as widgets, and there are all manner of bugs and side effects that come with it. Elements show up fine in CKEditor at first, but things start falling apart when trying to select or move them. Hence my realisation that I probably need to create a custom representation for them in the CKEditor view, so they're not handled by Angular and preventing these issues.